# consulta php sql SUM ( )

Tags: php, mysql

espero me puedan ayudar tengo una pagina en donde tengo que realizar una consulta que me sume y muestre los valores de una columna, cuando realizo la consulta en la base de datos me arroja bien el resultado: SELECT SUM(donadas) FROM entregados;

pero cuando la realizo desde php me arroja como resultado **1**

dejo captura de pantalla de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como código en php tengo el siguiente:

```
<?php
        require_once("connection.php");
        $query = "SELECT SUM(donadas) FROM entregados";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $numero = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo ''.$numero.'';
    ?> </br> Canastas Donadas
```

Espero me sepan entender, quedo atento a sus comentarios.
Gracias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM(donadas)` devuelve solo una fila con un número, por ejemplo:

```
+------------+
|SUM(donadas)|
+------------+
    35      
+------------+
```

`mysqli_num_rows($result);` trae la cantidad de filas devueltas en la consulta, o sea solo una (1), en este caso: **Una fila** con el numero **35**.

Se puede arreglar así:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(donadas) FROM entregados";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$numero = $row[0];
```

Comment: Estimado, te agradezco, fue la respuesta indicada. Saludos.